# Excel: replacing fastest time with the contestant's name

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I'm looking for a solution for this simple problem.

I'm trying to create an automatic worksheet to keep track of the fastest time. An idea is to track the fastest times with SMALL-function and it's working. I'd like to replace the fastest times with the contestants' names.

How to replace particular data with a data from another cell, if the time matches the contestant?

Edit: Here's the problem:
[image]

Comment: What's your `Small` function that works? I'm thinking you can use an `Index/Match` in there somehow.  What's the data look like?

Comment: As @BruceWayne asks, it would be very helpful if you'd post samples of the data (mustn't be real data)

Comment: Is your SMALL function referring to only a single column or does it run across columns? Is it =SMALL (B5:B8,1) or =SMALL (B5:E8,1) as an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, before I answer, I need to point out that the numbering format you use in time counter isn't a valid format that would be able to get calculated. You should probably have it with a period instead of a comma, like this: `03:35.174`

Now to your question...

The formula you need to use is (for `B10`):

```
=INDEX(A5:A8,MATCH(SMALL(B5:B8,1),B5:B8,0))
```

For `B11` you just need to change the `1` in the `SMALL` formula to a `2`. and to a `3` for `B12`.

This is the result:
[image]

And here is the Formula View:
[image]